# How would I create a list of items from a dataframe where none of its values are negative?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I'm trying to create an extracted list from a dataframe which lists out **all** the elements where its values don't meet a certain criteria. We'll use

```
+------------+--------+-------+
|  Date      | Object | Value |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 01/05/2010 | A      |   -10 |
| 01/05/2010 | A      |     5 |
| 01/05/2010 | A      |    20 |
| 01/05/2010 | B      |     5 |
| 01/05/2010 | B      |    10 |
| 01/05/2010 | B      |    31 |
| 01/05/2010 | C      |    -2 |
| 01/05/2010 | C      |     5 |
| 01/05/2010 | C      |    10 |
| 01/05/2010 | D      |    19 |
| 01/05/2010 | D      |    10 |
| 01/05/2010 | D      |    20 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

So let's say in the sample dataframe above there are several objects and values across dates,

I want to compile a series of all the objects that don't have ANY negative values (so in this case ['B', 'D']).

How do I go about this?

I've attempted `df["Values"].any() > 0` but that returned the following error message:

```
KeyError: False.
```

Comment: 1- please provide a reproducible input (not an image); 2- what is the exact matching expected output?

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`groupby.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html):

```
# are all values per object ≥ 0?
s = df['value'].ge(0).groupby(df['object']).all()

# keep objects that meet the above criterion, convert to list
out = s.index[s].tolist()
```

Output: `['B', 'D']`

Intermediate `s`:

```
object
A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a groupby to get the minimum value per object and then return any that have a minimum value of 0 or higher:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Object': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   'Value': [-10, 5, 20, 5, 10, 3, -2, 5, 10, 19, 10, 20]})

min_values = df.groupby('Object')['Value'].min()

non_neg = min_values[min_values >= 0]
```